# Csv Type Provider convert to Json

Tags: f#, json.net, type-providers

I am using the Csv Type Provider to read data from a local csv file.

I want to export the data as json, so I am taking each row and serializing it using the json.net Library with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)`.

The problem is that each row is modeled as a tuple, meaning that the column headers do not become property names when serializing. Instead I get Item1="..."; Item2="..." etc.

How can I export to Json without 'hand-rolling' a class/record type to hold the values and maintain the property names?

Comment: Are you using the type provider from the FSharp.Data library? Its documentation states [quite clearly](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) that it generates actual types with properties, not tuples.

Comment: Yep. The item type is `CsvProvider<...>.Row`. Intellisense shows the named properties so it feels like a record type but serializing suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeProvider works by providing *compile time* type safety. The actual code that is compiled maps (at compile time) the nice accessors to tupled values (for performance reasons, I guess). So at *run time* the JSON serializer sees tuples only.

AFAIK there is no way around hand-rolling records. (That is unless we eventually get type providers that are allowed to take types as parameters which would allow a `Lift<T>`-type provider or the CSV type provider implementation is adjusted accordingly.)

Comment: D'oh, I forgot that serialization happens at runtime and falls afoul of type erasure. I suppose a generative type provider might have solved Nick's problem?

Comment: @piaste Yes, depending on how the type providers types are implemented, that would work. However, that would create close coupling between the serialized representation, the serializer and the type provider. It might still make sense to introduce another *layer* of decoupling.